# How to retrieve a code snippet from html page with Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsp, html-parsing, jsoup

I want to parse Html page with Jsoup.

> html.page

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
   <div id="1">SomeText</div>
     <script>(function(a, b)){var fjs = a.getElementsByTagNames(b)[0]; … }      
     </script>
   <div class="class1">SomeText</div>
   <div class="class2">SomeText</div>
     <script>(function(c, d)){var fjs = c.getElementsByTagNames(d)[0]; … }     
     </script>
   <div class="class3">SomeText</div>
   <div class="class4">SomeText</div>
</body>
</html>
```

To retrieve some info I wrote the code:

```
File input = new File(filePath);
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(input, "UTF-8");
writer.write(document.getElementById("1").outerHtml() + "\n");
writer.write(document.getElementsByClass("class1").outerHtml() + "\n");
writer.write(document.getElementsByClass("class2").outerHtml() + "\n");
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

The output content of file is:

```
<div id="1">SomeText</div>
<div class="class1">SomeText</div>
<div class="class2">SomeText</div>
```

> What is the best way to receive the output file content like?

```
<div id="1">SomeText</div>
<script>(function(a, b)){var fjs = a.getElementsByTagNames(b)[0]; … }     
</script>
<div class="class1">SomeText</div>
<div class="class2">SomeText</div>
```

Comment: Your HTML is little broken since there is no opening `<body>` tag and `”` is not the same character as `"` which means that parser will optimize `id=”1”` to be `id="”1”"`so maybe change your editor to use `"` instead. Also could you explain what you want to achieve? From your question I suspect that you want to get code in `<body>` tag, but I am not sure about it.

Comment: Answering your own question is great ! To make it fit with SO's format, please move the part answering the question into an actual answer. No need to change which answer is _accepted_ though. It's perfectly acceptable here (and even encouraged) to answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [getElementByTag](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#getElementsByTag%28java.lang.String%29) and the write the result where you desire in your file

Answer (score 0):

```
File input = new File(filePath);
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(input, "UTF-8");
 writer.write(document.getElementById("1").outerHtml() + "\n");
 Elements scripts = document.getElementsByTag("script");
  for (Element script : scripts) {
   if (script.data().startsWith("(function(a, b)")) {
   writer.write(script.outerHtml() + "\n");
    }
  }
 writer.write(document.getElementsByClass("class1").outerHtml() + "\n");
 writer.write(document.getElementsByClass("class2").outerHtml() + "\n");
  writer.flush();
  writer.close();
```